# Brightness script makes image completely black and white

Tags: c#, image-processing, unity-game-engine, pixel, brightness

I want to change the brightness of the image I uploaded in my unity scene. Here's my current script:

```
public void AdjustBrightness(string brightness)
    {
        int brightnessInt = Convert.ToInt32(brightness);
        int mappedBrightness = (51 * brightnessInt) / 10 - 255;
        //Make an empty Texture the same same as the original 
        Texture2D bitmapImage = new Texture2D(imgTexture.width, imgTexture.height);

        if (mappedBrightness < -255) mappedBrightness = -255;
        if (mappedBrightness > 255) mappedBrightness = 255;
        Color color;
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmapImage.width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bitmapImage.height; j++)
            {
                color = bitmapImage.GetPixel(i, j);
                int cR = (int)color.r + mappedBrightness;
                int cG = (int)color.g + mappedBrightness;
                int cB = (int)color.b + mappedBrightness;

                if (cR < 0) cR = 0;
                if (cR > 255) cR = 255;

                if (cG < 0) cG = 0;
                if (cG > 255) cG = 255;

                if (cB < 0) cB = 0;
                if (cB > 255) cB = 255;

                bitmapImage.SetPixel(i, j,
    new Color((float)cR, (float)cG, (float)cB));
            }
        }
            //Apply all SetPixel changes
            bitmapImage.Apply();

            //Connect texture to material of GameObject this script is attached to 
            Image.renderer.material.mainTexture = bitmapImage as Texture;
    }
```

For some reason, this script completely changes my image to black. Then if I increase my values to a certain point, the image turns fully white.

Am I calculating brightness correctly here?

Btw, in the beginning I am mapping the brightness value from my current input range of values between 0% to 100% to -255 to 255 to use this script. Is this fine? That is, there is an input field to enter a brightness value of 0 to 100 and to use this formula, I have to map the value of 50% to what 50% means on the scale/range of -255 to 255 right?

Answer (score 1):

here i altered your script a little, try between 30 and 60% its still on the same scale as your script just color is in float between 0 and 1 and how your doing the math its either 0 black or 1 white try this and also your not getting the pixels of your image your getting the pixels of bitmapImage when you should be getting pixels of imgTexture i put the alpha into it too just incase you want to use a pic with alpha because that shouldnt change with the brightness

also i think you should probably keep a third copy of the Texture2D so you can restore it each time

```
public void AdjustBrightness(string brightness)
    {
        int brightnessInt = Convert.ToInt32(brightness);
        float mappedBrightness = (51 * brightnessInt) / 10 - 255;
        //Make an empty Texture the same same as the original 
        Texture2D bitmapImage = new Texture2D(imgTexture.width, imgTexture.height);

        if (mappedBrightness < -255) mappedBrightness = -255;
        if (mappedBrightness > 255) mappedBrightness = 255;
        Color color;
        for (int i = 0; i < bitmapImage.width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < bitmapImage.height; j++)
            {
                color = imgTexture.GetPixel(i, j);
                float cR;
                float cG;
                float cB;
                float cA;
                if(color.a == 1f){
                cR = color.r + (mappedBrightness/255);
                cG = color.g + (mappedBrightness/255);
                cB = color.b + (mappedBrightness/255);
                    cA = color.a;


                if (cR < 0) cR = 0;
                if (cR > 255) cR = 255;

                if (cG < 0) cG = 0;
                if (cG > 255) cG = 255;

                if (cB < 0) cB = 0;
                if (cB > 255) cB = 255;
                }else{
                    cR = color.r;
                    cG = color.g;
                    cB = color.b;
                    cA = color.a;
                }

                bitmapImage.SetPixel(i, j,
                                     new Color(cR, cG, cB,cA));
            }
        }
        //Apply all SetPixel changes
        bitmapImage.Apply();

        //Connect texture to material of GameObject this script is attached to 
        imgTexture = bitmapImage;
    }
```

Comment: Does my mappedBrightness make since though if I take an input brightness from 0 to 100 but this formula uses a scale of -255 to 255 input?

Comment: how your mapped brightness is makes 0 = -255 and 100 = 255

Comment: thats ok since i put (mappedBrightness/255) to add to the float its a range between -1 and 1 added to the actual color

Comment: But I am wondering ... that would make the image dark if brightness was at 0%, should the image brightness be regular at 0%?

Comment: Also, I can't have a range of -1 to 1 right? Shouldn't it be a range of 0 to 1 for float brightness?

Comment: 50 keeps the image how it is, less than 50 will make it darker and more than 50 will make it brighter

Comment: Okay great. Btw, do you know if there's a faster way to do this in Unity or is this the only way?

Comment: theres probably more ways but you can make a material with the diffuse shader and then change the main color just how you are in this method

Comment: definetly by messing around with materials

Comment: Hmm, can you provide me with an example of what you mean with the material with diffuse shader? I am thinking for this scenario, I have a texture2D object that is loaded let's say from Resources. You're saying I have to create with diffuse shader. Then attach script to that object? I think I am kind of doing something like that right now. The image I am loading has a default diffuse shader applied to it??

Comment: JRowan, btw, what do you mean by try "30% and 60%"? Should I be clipping my values to start and end with those?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using [this `Color` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx). Its members are neither `float`s nor `int`s, but `byte`s from 0 to 255.

I think when you're changing the brightness, you should *scale* `r`, `g`, and `b` by the same factor, instead of adding the same item to them all. Try this code:

```
public void AdjustBrightness(string brightnessString)
{
    float brightnessInput = Convert.ToFloat(brightnessString);
    if (brightnessInput < 0) brightnessInput = 0;
    if (brightnessInput > 100) brightnessInput = 100;
    float brightnessFactor = (brightnessInput/50.)*(brightnessInput/50.);
    //Make an empty Texture the same same as the original 
    Texture2D bitmapImage = new Texture2D(imgTexture.width, imgTexture.height);

    Color color;
    for (int i = 0; i < bitmapImage.width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < bitmapImage.height; j++)
        {
            color = bitmapImage.GetPixel(i, j);
            int cR = int(color.r * brightnessFactor);
            int cG = int(color.g * brightnessFactor);
            int cB = int(color.b * brightnessFactor);

            if (cR > 255) cR = 255;

            if (cG > 255) cG = 255;

            if (cB > 255) cB = 255;

            bitmapImage.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(cR, cG, cB));
        }
    }
        //Apply all SetPixel changes
        bitmapImage.Apply();

        //Connect texture to material of GameObject this script is attached to 
        Image.renderer.material.mainTexture = bitmapImage as Texture;
}
```

Using `FromArgb()` saves having to cast.

Also, using `.SetPixel()` is very slow. See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/617613/Fast-pixel-operations-in-NET-with-and-without-unsa for a way to push pixels more quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm doing this in Unity3d, so unfortunately, I'm not sure I can use LockBits or ColorMatrix. I might have to go with the slow method but possibly refactor it for efficiently? Also, I am using http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-ctor.html.

Comment: The search engines failed me. It looks like the function you should be using to adjust the brightness is `Lerp()` http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html

Comment: So since everything is really a `float`, why are you using an `int` at all? Just do all of your calculations as `float`s from 0-1.

Comment: Wait, using Color.Lerp is supposed to be faster?? Can you explain why? Give an example?

Comment: No, it's supposed to do the job of interpolating between two colors (the current one and white or black) subject to a number, meaning you don't need to reinvent the wheel.